# Changing time intervals for vSphere performance monitoring, and is there a better way?

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, performance-monitoring

I have a set of experiments running on a cluster node which is running ESXi 5.1, and I want to monitor the resource consumption on the node itself. Specifically, I am currently running experiments on a subset of the VMs on the ESXi host and wish to monitor resource consumption on those specific VMs.

Right now, since I'm using only a single ESXi host, I am using vSphere to access it and the performance reports. Ideally, I would like to get these reports for different time intervals.

I can already get the charts for a time interval of 1h, but these are rather long-running experiments and something like 2h, 3h,... would be preferable. However, I cannot seem to change the time interval. Here is an example of what my `Customize Performance Chart` dialog shows:

[image]

I am also running on a trial key at the moment.

How can I change this interval? Do I need a standard license, or do I just need to turn off the VM (unlikely, but I haven't attempted it yet as these are long-running experiments)?

Any help (or pointers to documentation which deals with the above -- I've already looked but did not find much) would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you click on `Custom` instead of `Real-time`?

Comment: Sorry, I switched the images I had intended to upload around. The edited picture is what my current vSphere client shows me (i.e., no `custom` entry). The previous picture was how it *should* look. I'm wondering whether this is because of it being in evaluation mode.

Comment: OK, that was what confused me...I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a single esxi host without vCenter and connect directly to the host, you'll only see real-time performance.  You need vCenter in order to see historical data.

However, there is a workaround.  If you get Veeam One (free) you can see historical data that you are after (for the most part...there are some limitations compared to the paid version).

Comment: Since this answered my original question, I'm accepting it as an answer. Thank you for mentioning Veeam One, I'll be taking a look at it as soon as I can.